# Ember Data Filtering

Tags: ember.js

I am having trouble outputting one to many Ember data. The data is getting loaded into Ember Data properly per the developer tools tab. But I'm unable to access the categories for some reason.

game model

```
//app/models/game.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    gameCategory: DS.belongsTo('game-category'),
    gameName: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

gameCategory model

```
//app/models/game-category.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    gameCategory: DS.attr('string'),
    games: DS.hasMany('games')
});
```

The JSON returned to model.gameCategory

```
{"game":
    [
      {"id":1,"gameName":"Monopoly","gameCategory":"Board Games"},
      {"id":2,"gameName":"Chess","gameCategory":"Board Games"},
      {"id":3,"gameName":"Zelda","gameCategory":"Video Games"},
      {"id":4,"gameName":"Mario","gameCategory":"Video Games"}
    ],
 "gameCategory":
    [
      {"id":"Board Games", "gameCategory": "Board Games", "games": [1, 2]},
      {"id":"Video Games", "gameCategory": "Video Games", "games": [3, 4]}
    ]
}
```

Template

```
//app/templates/games.hbs
{{#each model.gameCategory as |cat|}}
    <div class="cat">{{cat.gameCategory}}
    {{#each cat.games as |game|}}
        <div class="game">{{game.gameName}}</div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I guess REST response model name should be `game-category` instead of `gameCategory`. and also `games: DS.hasMany('games')` should be `games: DS.hasMany('game')`

Comment: Also it is important to know what Adapter are you using (JSONAPIAdapter or RESTAdapder) .. the Json response isn't JSONAPIAdapter compliant.

Comment: kumkanillam: I changed both of those things, but I am still only getting access to games and not gameCategory.

Comment: SDen: I'm using RESTAdapter